How can I load Gio Resources in Gtk4?
I am trying to load a theme from a resource file
style.css
The following is a basic style that I need to apply
window {
    background-color: orchid;
}

main.c
I then write a basic gtk application and try to load a simple CSS style
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

extern GResource *gresources_get_resource(void);

static void activate(GtkApplication* application, gpointer data) {
  GtkWidget* window = gtk_application_window_new(application);
  GtkCssProvider* provider = gtk_css_provider_new();
  GdkDisplay* display = gdk_display_get_default();
  gchar* path = "/com/example/app/css/style.css";
  gtk_css_provider_load_from_resource(provider, path);
  gtk_style_context_add_provider_for_display(display, (GtkStyleProvider*)provider, 600);
  gtk_widget_set_size_request(window, 854, 480);
  gtk_window_present((GtkWindow*)window);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  GtkApplication* application = gtk_application_new("com.example.app", 0);
  g_resources_register(gresources_get_resource());
  g_signal_connect(application, "activate", (GCallback)activate, NULL);
  g_application_run((GApplication*)application, argc, argv);
  g_object_unref(application);
  return 0;
}

gresources.xml
The following is a simple resource file
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gresources>
  <gresource prefix="/com/example/app/css">
    <file>css/style.css</file>
  </gresource>
</gresources>

I generate gresource.c and compile as follows
glib-compile-resources --generate-source gresources.xml
gcc $(pkg-config --cflags gtk4) main.c gresources.c -o main $(pkg-config --libs gtk4)

The program outputs
(main:44395): Gtk-WARNING **: 13:58:23.068: Theme parser error: <broken file>:1:1: The resource at “/com/example/app/css/style.css” does not exist

It seems my gresource.xml was wrong
Wrong
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gresources>
  <gresource prefix="/com/example/app/css">
    <file>css/style.css</file>
  </gresource>
</gresources>

Correct
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gresources>
  <gresource prefix="/com/example/app">
    <file>css/style.css</file>
  </gresource>
</gresources>

According to the documentation I shouldn't subpaths are to be put in th <file>subpath/file.ext</file> tag not <resource prefix="../subpath"></gresource>
